# Parse XML item "Category" into an NSArray with NSDictionary

Tags: xml, ios, nsarray, nsdictionary, nsxmlparser

### Question:

The generated XML file from an .XSD template produces the output pasted below. Since **`category`**'s keys are **`image`**, my standard way of parsing the `image` items wont work on `category`. I would like to place the **`category name="Category #"`** into an array, How can I make an array from the category fields.

### What I need:

What I want is an array of dictionaries. Each position contains a dictionary representing one category, and each dictionary contains images for that category.

> `Array: @"Category 1",@"Category 2",@"Category 3";`
>
> `For each Array, a Dictionary with: <image>` *and everything in between* `</image>`
>
> ***Basically, I need to create a plist like the following image, from the XML data source***

[image]

### XML Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<app xmlns="http://www.wrightscs.com/_xml_.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.wrightscs.com/_xml_.xsd" name="Testing" unlock_product_id="com.wrightscs.all">
    <bannerImg>http://www.wrightscs.com</bannerImg> 
    <category name="Category 1" icon="http://www.wrightscs.com">
        <image>
                <title>title</title>
                <thumbUrl>http://www.wrightscs.com</thumbUrl>
                <sampleUrl>http://www.wrightscs.com</sampleUrl>
                <imageUrl>http://www.wrightscs.com</imageUrl>
                <description>These items / keys not an issue.</description>
                <infoUrl>http://www.wrightscs.com</infoUrl>
                <license>http://www.wrightscs.com</license>
                <licenseUrl>http://www.wrightscs.com</licenseUrl>
        </image>
    </category>
    <category name="Category 2" icon="http://www.wrightscs.com">
        <image>
                <title>title</title>
                <thumbUrl>http://www.wrightscs.com</thumbUrl>
                <sampleUrl>http://www.wrightscs.com</sampleUrl>
                <imageUrl>http://www.wrightscs.com</imageUrl>
                <description>These items / keys not an issue.</description>
                <infoUrl>http://www.wrightscs.com</infoUrl>
                <license>http://www.wrightscs.com</license>
                <licenseUrl>http://www.wrightscs.com</licenseUrl>
        </image>
    </category> 
    <category name="Category 3" icon="http://www.wrightscs.com">
        <image>
                <title>title</title>
                <thumbUrl>http://www.wrightscs.com</thumbUrl>
                <sampleUrl>http://www.wrightscs.com</sampleUrl>
                <imageUrl>http://www.wrightscs.com</imageUrl>
                <description>These items / keys not an issue.</description>
                <infoUrl>http://www.wrightscs.com</infoUrl>
                <license>http://www.wrightscs.com</license>
                <licenseUrl>http://www.wrightscs.com</licenseUrl>
        </image>
    </category>
</app>
```

*Note: none of the other items / keys are an issue, I am only interested in making category into an array. The URL's in this example are also replaced from the original content.*

Comment: Your title indicates your question has been answered, what's the solution?

Comment: @Nick http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5797736/parse-xml-item-category-into-an-nsarray-with-nsdictionary-solved/5845371#5845371

Comment: Thanks for posting it here. It keeps SO tidy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The Solution:

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Delegate Received

-(void)parsingComplete:(XMLDataSource*)theParser {
    NSArray *categoryArray = [theParser getCategories];
    [categoryArray writeToFile:PLIST atomically:YES];
}
- (void)receivedItems:(NSArray *)theItems {
    NSMutableArray *dataItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [dataItems addObjectsFromArray:[NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:PLIST]];

    NSDictionary * dataItem = [dataItems objectAtIndex:categoryIndex];
    data_ =  [dataItem objectForKey:@"images"];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"updateThumbs" object:nil];
}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Parsing Delegates

- (void)parse:(NSData *)data withDelegate:(id)sender onComplete:(SEL)callback 
{
    parentDelegate = sender;
    onCompleteCallback = callback;
    loading = YES;

    NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:data];
    [parser setDelegate:self];
    [parser setShouldProcessNamespaces:NO];
    [parser setShouldReportNamespacePrefixes:NO];
    [parser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:NO];
    [parser parse];
}
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser parseErrorOccurred:(NSError *)parseError {
    parsed = NO;
    loading = NO;
}
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI
qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict 
{
    NSString *element = [elementName stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
    currentElement = element;
    if ([[currentElement lowercaseString] isEqual:@"image"]) {
        inImage = YES;
        itemsDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        [itemsDictionary addEntriesFromDictionary:attributeDict];
    }

    if ([[currentElement lowercaseString] isEqual:@"category"]) {
        inCategory = YES;
        categoryDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        [categoryDictionary addEntriesFromDictionary:attributeDict];
    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI
qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName 
{
    NSString *element = [elementName stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
    if ([[element lowercaseString] isEqual:@"image"]) {
        inImage = NO;
        [items addObject:[itemsDictionary copy]];
    }

    if ([[element lowercaseString] isEqual:@"category"]) {
        inCategory = NO;
        [categoryDictionary setObject:[items copy] forKey:@"images"];
        [items removeAllObjects];
        [categories addObject:[categoryDictionary copy]];
    }
}
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string 
{
    NSString *stringValue = [string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
    NSString *element = [currentElement stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

    /*  skip over blank elements.  */
    if (stringValue == nil || [stringValue isEqual:@""]) {
        return;
    }

    if (element != nil && [element length] > 0) {
        if (inImage) {
            if ([itemsDictionary objectForKey:element] != nil) {
                [itemsDictionary setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", [itemsDictionary objectForKey:element], stringValue]
                                    forKey:element];
            } else {
                [itemsDictionary setObject:stringValue forKey:element];
            }
        } else if ((!inImage) && (inCategory)) {
            if ([categoryDictionary objectForKey:element] != nil) {
                [categoryDictionary setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", [categoryDictionary objectForKey:element], stringValue]
                                       forKey:element];
            } else {
                [categoryDictionary setObject:stringValue forKey:element];
            }
        } else {
            if ([root objectForKey:element] != nil) {
                [root setObject:stringValue forKey:element];
            }
        }
    }
}
- (void)parserDidStartDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser {
    NSError * err;
    if(![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:PLIST]) {
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:PLIST error:&err];
    }
}
- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser 
{
    parsed = YES;
    loading = NO;

    if ([parentDelegate respondsToSelector:onCompleteCallback]) {
        [parentDelegate performSelector:onCompleteCallback withObject:self];
    }

    if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(receivedItems:)])
        [self receivedItems:items];
    else
        SHOW_ALERT(@"parserDidEndDocument:", @"receivedItems: not responding!", nil, @"Okay", nil)
}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Setters / Getters

- (id)delegate {
    return self;
}
- (void)setDelegate:(id)new_delegate {
    _delegate = self;
}
- (BOOL)isSuccessful {
    return success;
}
- (BOOL)isLoading {
    return loading;
}
- (BOOL)isParsed {
    return parsed;
}
- (NSArray *)getCategories {
    return categories;
}
- (NSDictionary *)getRoot {
    return root;
}
- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

take a look to xpath and this: http://blog.objectgraph.com/index.php/2010/02/24/parsing-html-iphone-development/

in this case the xpath you need is

//category/@name

this with the library mentioned above should return the categories names in a array.

for more xpath syntax, check this: http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/default.asp

Comment: Don't like hpple too much, but I revised my question.